# John Resig's simple class instantiation and "use strict"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, use-strict

Reference : http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/

```
// makeClass - By John Resig (MIT Licensed)
function makeClass(){
  return function(args){
    if ( this instanceof arguments.callee ) {
      if ( typeof this.init == "function" )
        this.init.apply( this, args.callee ? args : arguments );
    } else
      return new arguments.callee( arguments );
  };
}
```

I was wondering, if there are any ECMAScript 5 compliant way to implement the same functionality. The problem is, accessing `arguments.callee` is deprecated in strict mode.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it `arguments.callee` isn't *deprecated* in strict mode, in which case you could continue to use it; rather, it has been *removed* and attempted use will (or is supposed to) throw an exception.

The workaround is to use named anonymous functions, if you'll forgive the oxymoron. Really I should say ["named function expressions"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Named_function_expression). An example:

```
function someFunc(){
  return function funcExpressionName(args){
    if (this instanceof funcExpressionName) {
      // do something
    } else
      return new funcExpressionName( arguments );
  };
}
```

The name you provide, in my example `funcExpressionName` is not supposed to be accessible from anywhere except inside the function it applies to, but unfortunately IE has other ideas (as you can see if you [Google it](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=named+function+expression+IE)).

For the example in your question I'm not sure how to handle the `args.callee` since I don't know how that is set by the calling function, but the use of `arguments.callee` would be replaced as per my example.

Answer (score 2):

The above idea given by *nnnnnn* is quite good. And in order to avoid IE issues I suggest the following solution.

```
function makeClassStrict() {
    var isInternal, instance;

    var constructor = function(args) {
        // Find out whether constructor was called with 'new' operator.
        if (this instanceof constructor) {
            // When an 'init' method exists, apply it to the context object.
            if (typeof this.init == "function") {
                // Ask private flag whether we did the calling ourselves.
                this.init.apply( this, isInternal ? args : arguments ); 
            }
        } else {
            // We have an ordinary function call.

            // Set private flag to signal internal instance creation.
            isInternal = true;                                           
            instance = new constructor(arguments);
            isInternal = false;                                         
            return instance;
        }
    };

    return constructor;
}
```

Note how we avoid reference to `args.callee` in the `// do something` part by using an internal flag.

Answer (score 1):

John Resig's original code fails with a parameterless constructor.

```
var Timestamp = makeClass();
Timestamp.prototype.init = function() {
    this.value = new Date();
};

// ok
var timestamp = Timestamp();
alert( timestamp.value );  

// TypeError: args is undefined
var timestamp = new Timestamp();
alert( timestamp.value );
```

But it can be repaired using the following line

```
this.init.apply( this, args && args.callee ? args : arguments );
```