# How to define a function and use only when needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing an MVC app. Up until now I wrote the whole JS code into the views. This is against good practices. Now i am trying to move a part of the code to separate files and then include it into the views. This is code sample:

```
var scripts = function() {
  var _foo = function foo(){
    // ...
  }

  return {
    init: function () {
      _foo ();
    }
  };
}();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  scripts.init();
});
```

This is what my .js file looks like and works as well. But if I want to define function with parameters as follow:

```
var scripts = function() {
  var _foo = function foo(params) {
    // ...
  }

  return {
    init: function () {
      _foo ();
      _foo ;
    }
  };
}();
```

I receive an error in console 'The _foo is not defined' on firing the function. Is there a way just to define the function and use it when it is needed?

Comment: What a title - _How to Do?_.  Describes _nothing_.  Impressive.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `_foo;` after the `_foo()` call and why you are not calling it with some parameter as it's defined above? `_foo()` and `_foo(param)` doesn't look the same functions from the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the answers. Take me some time to get back here, but I have a solution that's suits me. I will explain my self little more before paste a code solution. The case was that I needed a function that accept params but I want to use it when it is time. For example if you have javascript function that accept html element like 'input type=file' and you want on change event on this html element to pass it to this function. I hope the example was clear enough.This is a simple example of code what I was looking for:

```
var Scripts = function(){
  var _example =function(params){
    code.....
  };
  return {
     init:function(){
      ...call some other functions.....
     },
     example:_example 
  }

}();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  Scripts.init();
})



Scripts.example(params);...call function like this in tour code...
```

Answer (score 1):

> I receive an error in console 'The _foo is not defined' on firing the function.

It is unclear what you mean here. In the code below, `_foo` is a local variable within the anonymous function that assigns the object with `init: function(){ ...` to the `scripts` variable. Thus, by calling `scripts.init()`, `_foo` is accessible and called, as demonstrated below.

But, if you call `_foo()` directly, it is not defined and accessible in the global scope (since it is a private local variable in the anonymous function).

```js
var scripts = function() {
  var _foo = function foo(params) {
    // ...
    console.log('_foo called');
  }

  return {
    init: function () {
      _foo ();
    }
  };
}();

scripts.init();
_foo(); // will not work, as it is not accessible in global scope
```

> Is there a way just to define the function and use it when it is needed?

Sure, you can make it accessible as a method of the `scripts` variable, like this:

```js
var scripts = function() {
  var _foo = function foo(params) {
    // ...
    console.log('_foo called with ' + (params ? '' : 'no ') + 'params.');
  }

  return {
    init: function () {
      _foo ();
    },
    _foo: _foo // make _foo accessible on scripts
  };
}();

scripts.init();
scripts._foo('a parameter');
```

Comment: what does that second `_foo ;` in the `init` function do?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, it does nothing, I just kept it to mirror the OP code, but could as well remove it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do functions within an object.  As an alternative to your "scripts" object,  Here I use the prototype and the `makeClassStrict` (from another question on this site) here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17588082/125981)

This creates an object called "MyClass" to which I may add functions such as here my `newFoo` function with parameters.  I also illustrate the `init` function concept you have in your post which allows me to pass parameters to the init simply at time of instance creation by simply passing paramters to my `MyClass()` as `var newInstanceThing = MyClass("fred");` for example.

Note also I added a function called `origFoo`

```js
/* JavaScript makeClass example */
/* http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/ */
// makeClassStrict - By Hubert Kauker 
// original by John Resig (MIT Licensed).
function makeClassStrict() {
  var isInternal, instance;

  var constructor = function(args) {
    // Find out whether constructor was called with 'new' operator.
    if (this instanceof constructor) {
      // When an 'init' method exists, apply it to the context object.
      if (typeof this.init == "function") {
        // Ask private flag whether we did the calling ourselves.
        this.init.apply(this, isInternal ? args : arguments);
      }
    } else {
      // We have an ordinary function call.

      // Set private flag to signal internal instance creation.
      isInternal = true;
      instance = new constructor(arguments);
      isInternal = false;
      return instance;
    }
  };

  return constructor;
}
var MyClass = makeClassStrict(); // create object
MyClass.prototype = {
  origFoo: function(mything) {
    return mything;
  }
}
//  add init to my new "MyClass" prototype, could be in object above also
MyClass.prototype.init = function(newText, newThing) {
  this.someText = newText == undefined ? 'defaultText' : newText;
  this.newThing = newThing == undefined ? 'defaultThing' : newThing;
  this.gobble = 'turkey';
  this.cracker = 'cheese';
}
// add a new function newFoo
MyClass.prototype.newFoo = function(foome, foometwice) {
  this.foo = foome;
  this.foo2 = foometwice;
}
// add a new string object to the prototype
MyClass.prototype.otherText = 'otherstuff';

// create instance of my class with parameter for newText
var trustme = MyClass('trustmedude'); // init gets used
console.log(trustme.someText + ":" + trustme.newThing);
console.log(trustme.origFoo("wilber was here"));

// create instance with parameter for newText and newThing
var iam = MyClass('some new text', 'mything');
console.log(trustme.newThing); // logs defaultThing
console.log(iam.someText); //logs "some new text"
iam.someText = 'hi fred'; // change it for this instance
console.log(iam.someText); //logs "hi fred"
console.log(iam.otherText); // logs "otherstuff" set above
console.log(iam.newThing); //logs "mything"
// note don't use the prototype directly
console.log(MyClass.someText); //logs undefined
console.log(MyClass.otherText); //logs undefined
// these are in the instance
console.log(iam.cracker + iam.gobble); //logs "cheeseturkey"
console.log(iam.hasOwnProperty("someText")); //logs true
// show that they ARE different in each instance
console.log(iam.gobble + ":" + trustme.gobble + ":" + trustme.someText + ":" + iam.someText);
// do our foo function and properties stuff
iam.newFoo("fooby", 123);
console.log(iam.foo, iam.foo2);
```