# $(this) not set in the jQuery UI dialog "open" option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, closures, jquery-ui-dialog

At the bottom of a word game there are 4 buttons, which open jQuery UI dialogs with certain words from the game dictionary:

[image: game screenshot]

I am trying to simplify the game code by creating the following function:

```
// select word using the filterFunc and then concat them all to a string
function filterWords(filterFunc) {
    // the words already filtered and assigned to the dialog's innerHTML
    if ($(this).html().length > 1000) {
        return (ev, ui) => {};
    }

    // filter the keys of HASHED dictionary by calling the filterFunc on each
    const filtered = Object.keys(HASHED)
        .filter(word => filterFunc(word))
        .reduce((result, word) => {
            return result + 
                '<p><span class="tile">' + word + '</span> ' + HASHED[word] + '</p>'
        }, '');

    // return the closure expected by the dialog's "open" option
    return (ev, ui) => {
        $(this).html(filtered);
        const title = $(this).dialog('option', 'title');
        console.log(title + ': ' + filtered.length + ' chars');
    };
}
```

My hope is that jQuery UI dialog "open" option expects a `function (ev, ui) {}` and that is what I am trying to give it by my new function:

```
const twoDlg = $('#twoDlg').dialog({
    modal: true,
    appendTo: '#fullDiv',
    autoOpen: false,
    open: filterWords(word => word.length == 2),
    buttons: {
        'Close': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

Here another dialog:

```
const rare2Dlg = $('#rare2Dlg').dialog({
    modal: true,
    appendTo: '#fullDiv',
    autoOpen: false,
    open: filterWords(word => word.indexOf('X') >= 0),
    buttons: {
        'Close': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, now I get the error message:

```
jquery.js:4095  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at filterWords (test?player=abcde:833:594)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (test?player=abcde:835:139)
    at mightThrow (jquery.js:3802:29)
    at process (jquery.js:3870:12)
```

Which indicates to me that `$(this).html()` is not valid in my closure.

Is there a way to get it working?

**UPDATE:**

I have prepared a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/7Lktcwae/) with 3 dialogs and 3 buttons to open. The method `filterWordsWorks()` works, but has too much repeated code. The commented out method `open: filterWordsBroken(word => word.length == 2),` fails.

And below the same demo code, inlined into Stackoverflow:

```js
'use strict';

const HASHED = {
  "one": "Word description 1",
  "two": "Word description 2",
  "three": "Word description 3",
  "four": "Word description 4",
  "five": "Word description 5",
  "six": "Word description 6",
  "seven": "Word description 7"
};

// select word using the filterFunc and then concat them all to a string
function filterWordsBroken(filterFunc) {
  // the words already filtered and assigned to the dialog's innerHTML
  if ($(this).html().length > 1000) {
    return (ev, ui) => {};
  }

  // filter the keys of HASHED dictionary by calling the filterFunc on each
  const filtered = Object.keys(HASHED)
    .filter(word => filterFunc(word))
    .reduce((result, word) => {
      return result +
        '<p>' + word + ': ' + HASHED[word] + '</p>'
    }, '');

  // return the closure expected by the dialog's "open" option
  return (ev, ui) => {
    $(this).html(filtered);
    const title = $(this).dialog('option', 'title');
    console.log(title + ': ' + filtered.length + ' chars');
  };
}

// select word using the filterFunc and then concat them all to a string
function filterWordsWorks(filterFunc) {
  return Object.keys(HASHED)
    .filter(word => filterFunc(word))
    .reduce((result, word) => {
      return result +
        '<p>' + word + ': ' + HASHED[word] + '</p>'
    }, '');
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  const twoDlg = $('#twoDlg').dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    //open: filterWordsBroken(word => word.length == 2),
    open: function(ev, ui) {
      // prevent this code from running twice
      if ($(this).html().length < 1000) {
        const filtered = filterWordsWorks(word => word.length == 2);
        $(this).html(filtered);
        const title = $(this).dialog('option', 'title');
        console.log(title + ': ' + filtered.length);
      }
    }
  });
  const threeDlg = $('#threeDlg').dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    //open: filterWordsBroken(word => word.length == 3),
    open: function(ev, ui) {
      // prevent this code from running twice
      if ($(this).html().length < 1000) {
        const filtered = filterWordsWorks(word => word.length == 3);
        $(this).html(filtered);
        const title = $(this).dialog('option', 'title');
        console.log(title + ': ' + filtered.length);
      }
    }
  });
  const fourDlg = $('#fourDlg').dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    //open: filterWordsBroken(word => word.length == 3),
    open: function(ev, ui) {
      // prevent this code from running twice
      if ($(this).html().length < 1000) {
        const filtered = filterWordsWorks(word => word.length == 4);
        $(this).html(filtered);
        const title = $(this).dialog('option', 'title');
        console.log(title + ': ' + filtered.length);
      }
    }
  });

  $('#twoBtn').button().click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    twoDlg.dialog('open');
  });

  $('#threeBtn').button().click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    threeDlg.dialog('open');
  });

  $('#fourBtn').button().click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    fourDlg.dialog('open');
  });
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui@1/dist/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui@1/dist/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- beware: the twoDlg will be empty -->
<DIV ID="twoDlg" TITLE="2 letters"></DIV>
<DIV ID="threeDlg" TITLE="3 letters"></DIV>
<DIV ID="fourDlg" TITLE="4 letters"></DIV>

<BUTTON ID="twoBtn">2 letters</BUTTON>
<BUTTON ID="threeBtn">3 letters</BUTTON>
<BUTTON ID="fourBtn">4 letters</BUTTON>
```

Comment: `open: filterWords(word => word.indexOf('X') >= 0),` will return the result of `filterWords(word => word.indexOf('X') >= 0)` to the `open:` option - you *probably* wanted `open: () => filterWords(word => word.indexOf('X') >= 0),`  (without looking too closely)

Comment: Yes, that is what I want: my `filterWords` returns a closure

Comment: the open event handler has this form `open: function( event, ui ) {}` perhaps call your function in that anonymous  one - note `ui` is only for consistency ref: https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open  Note you are using `this` but not passing that to your function

Comment: I know, that is what my current code is doing... But now I am trying to change it to have a method (called `filterWords`) returning a `function( event, ui ) {}` closure, with a condition (a 2-letter word; a word containing "X"; etc.) *embedded* in it.

Comment: Give me a minute to toss together a working example with some of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as much of this as you wish.

This is NOT a direct answer to the question but more an x/y example of what your stated goal is: less code

Since you indicated your desire was less code here is a simpler example.

- Uses some data attributes in the buttons and dialog

  - Note how dialog 3 has none and uses the code default `wordLength: 3,`
- Use a class for all the buttons to target them in code
- Use a class for all the dialogs to target them in code
- Data attribute on the button to say which dialog it points to.
- Used some literals as for example (with back quote on them)

  ```
  `${myvar}text more text${anothervar} fun`;
  ```
- Removed the `preventDefault` from the button click and instead used the `type="button"` on the elements
- Chained the  `$('.my-letter-dialog') .on("dialogopen"` and the `.dialog(` - order matters as `.dialog(` does not return jQuery but the event handler does.

You COULD create a dialog from ONE dialog - added a "5" letter example for that but it could be all of them.

```js
'use strict';

const HASHED = {
  "one": "Word description 1",
  "two": "Word description 2",
  "three": "Word description 3",
  "four": "Word description 4",
  "five": "Word description 5",
  "six": "Word description 6",
  "seven": "Word description 7"
};
jQuery(function($) {
  function filterFunc(word, len) {
    //console.log(word, len, word.length == len);
    return word.length == len;
  }
  $('.my-letter-dialog')
    .on("dialogopen", function(event, ui) {
      let elWLen = $(this).data('wordlength');
      let wordLen = !!elWLen ? elWLen : $(this).dialog("option", "wordLength");
      console.log(wordLen);
      if ($(this).html().length > 1000) {
        return (ev, ui) => {};
      }
      const filtered = Object.keys(HASHED)
        .filter(word => filterFunc(word, wordLen))
        .reduce((result, word) => {
          return `${result}<p>${word}:${HASHED[word]}</p>`
        }, '');
      //console.log('filtered:', filtered)
      $(this).html(filtered);
      const title = $(this).dialog('option', 'title');
      const newTitle = `${title}:${filtered.length} chars`;
      $(this).dialog('option', 'title', newTitle);
    })
    .dialog({
      modal: true,
      autoOpen: false,
      wordLength: 3,
      filterFunc: filterFunc
    });

  $('.my-letter-button').button()
    .on("click", function(ev) {
      const targ = $(this).data('targetselector');
      $(targ).dialog('open');
    });
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui@1/dist/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui@1/dist/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- beware: the twoDlg will be empty -->
<div class="my-letter-dialog" id="twoDlg" data-wordlength="2" title="2 letters"></div>
<div class="my-letter-dialog" id="threeDlg" title="3 letters"></div>
<div class="my-letter-dialog" id="fourDlg" data-wordlength="4" title="4 letters"></div>

<button class="my-letter-button" type="button" id="twoBtn" data-targetselector="#twoDlg">2 letters</button>
<button class="my-letter-button" type="button" id="threeBtn" data-targetselector="#threeDlg">3 letters</button>
<button class="my-letter-button" type="button" id="fourBtn" data-targetselector="#fourDlg">4 letters</button>
```

Comment: Do you think it is possible to pass a comparison function via `$(this).data`? Or via some context object attached to the dialog t its creation time? Because I don' only look at the word length, but also have 2 buttons with `word=>word.indexOf('Q')>=0` and `word=>word.indexOf('X')>=0` in my real game...

Comment: Determine what your context is and if it can be garnered/accessed via the `this` - one of the reasons I put up the extension option initially is you can perhaps leverage that to your advantage here - don't be discouraged by the perceived complexity as understanding this is a lot about JavaScript and "context" here of the instance in play. Review this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057816/john-resigs-simple-class-instantiation-and-use-strict/17588082#17588082 and some other posts by Hubert on here as understanding the basics behind jQuery which the jQuery UI uses can help

Comment: Of course you can also look up Jon Resig on here for links to other insight into jQuery from when he released in initial version back when he was in college in 2006.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty rough but here I created a UI widget method called `filterWords` and added that to the `ui.dialog` then showed how to call it with a button.

Alternately I added a method that gets called on the dialog open.

Notes:

- dialog `filterWords` also triggers the open
- commented out a good bit of your code for this demo as I did not have `HASHED` available.
- added an open handler if you wish to go that direction
- note how the widget code uses `this.element`
- widget doc: https://jqueryui.com/widget/
- note how the dialog is available as `$(this)` as I show in the RAW function with `$(this).find('.words')` element log of the html
- I added some additional code to show how your word count can be an option `wordcount:2,`

There are probably other ways to make this more efficient but here I just show a lot of options available here.

```js
$.widget("ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog, {
  filterWords: function(event) {
    let count = this.options.wordcount;
    console.log(count);
    console.log('we are here!');
    //console.log(this.element);
    let myWords = this.element.find('.words');
    console.log('words:', myWords.length, myWords.html());
    $(this).trigger('open');

    /*
           // the words already filtered and assigned to the dialog's innerHTML
    if ($(this).find('.words').html().length > 1000) {
        return (ev, ui) => {};
    }

    // filter the keys of HASHED dictionary by calling the filterFunc on each
    const filtered = Object.keys(HASHED)
        .filter(word => filterFunc(word))
        .reduce((result, word) => {
            return result + 
                '<p><span class="tile">' + word + '</span> ' + HASHED[word] + '</p>'
        }, '');

    // return the closure expected by the dialog's "open" option
    return (ev, ui) => {
        $(this).html(filtered);
        const title = $(this).dialog('option', 'title');
        console.log(title + ': ' + filtered.length + ' chars');
    };
     */
  }
});


function filterWordsRaw(event, ui) {
  console.log('in RAW form');
  console.log($(this).find('.words').html());
  // the words already filtered and assigned to the dialog's innerHTML
  if ($(this).html().length > 1000) {
    return (ev, ui) => {};
  }
  /* commented out as I do not have HASHED defined 
    // filter the keys of HASHED dictionary by calling the filterFunc on each
    const filtered = Object.keys(HASHED)
      .filter(word => filterFunc(word))
      .reduce((result, word) => {
        return result +
          '<p><span class="tile">' + word + '</span> ' + HASHED[word] + '</p>'
      }, '');

    // return the closure expected by the dialog's "open" option
    return (ev, ui) => {
      $(this).html(filtered);
      const title = $(this).dialog('option', 'title');
      console.log(title + ': ' + filtered.length + ' chars');
    };
    */
}

/* just to show we did this */
function handleOpen(event) {
  console.log('opened');
  console.log(event.target === this);
}

$(".selector").dialog({
  modal: true,
  appendTo: '#fullDiv',
  autoOpen: false,
  open: handleOpen,
  wordcount: 2,
  buttons: {
    'Close': function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  }
});

$(".selector").on("dialogopen", filterWordsRaw);

$('.go-do-it').on('click', function(event) {
  console.log('hi');
  $(".selector").dialog("filterWords");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="go-do-it">Click</button>
</div>

<div class="selector" title="Dialog Title">
  <span class="words">one fish two fish red fish blue fish</span>
</div>
<div id="fullDiv"></div>
```

Comment: not really fully functional but more to illustrate how to extend the UI dialog and use some things associated with jQuery and jQuery UI widgets

Comment: note in the dialog extension I hacked togiether you would access `$(this).html(filtered);` as `this.element.html(filtered);`

Comment: Mark, thank you for effort and I love the motto at your profile page! However your suggested fix is hard to understand for me. So I have prepared [my own jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/7Lktcwae/) with 3 dialogs and 3 buttons to open. The method `filterWordsWorks()` works but has too much repeated code. The commented out method `open: filterWordsBroken(word => word.length == 2),` fails. I will update my question with the demo too.